# vectorize C++ code to improve STL performance

Tags: optimization, gcc, intel, compiler-optimization, vectorization

I am doing calculations on values contained in several large STL vector containers in an application built using C++/ Linux/ GCC / Windows XP/ Intel compiler

Is it worthwile investigating optimization opprtunity with vectorization by changing aligment attributes or using intel library functions, etc. - or the comipler automatically takes care?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the compiler will take care of it with the appropriate settings, so you'll have to tweak a bit.

That said, if you target a specific hardware, you'd better make sure the compiler does take advantage of such system. For example Intel compiler is known to be an excellent optimizer for their processors.

Now, sometimes it's also good to manually vectorize. In fact it's like any optimization : first implement a simple readable version with an efficient algorithm. Then optimize the code using a profiler. The profiler will let you know where to concentrate your efforts.

If you know you'll have one particular function crunching members, and have experience with the generated code (from the compiler) for this kind of function, you might start to apply some optimization from the very start but make sure you already know what will be generated.